# Nav link not working when I print Kartik widget

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2

I have searched a lot and tried many solutions  but not able to resolve this issue.

when I print this grid nav bar drop down stop working.

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider,
    //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'pjax'=>true,
    'striped'=>true,
    'hover'=>true,
    'panel'=>[
                'type'=>'primary',
                //'type'=>GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,
                //'heading'=>'Vacancies' // $heading,
            ],
    'responsive'=>true,
    'hover'=>true,
    'resizableColumns'=>true,
    'persistResize'=>false,

    'toolbar'=> [
    '{toggleData}',
    '{export}',
    ],

    'export'=>[
        'FontAwesome'=>true,
        'showConfirmAlert' => false,
        "messages"=>false ,
        'enableFormatter'=>false,
        'target'=>['ExportMenu'=>'TARGET_SELF'],
        //'asDropdown'=>true,
    ],
    'exportConfig' => [
    GridView::EXCEL => [
        'label' => 'Excel',
        'icon' => $isFa ? 'file-excel-o' : 'floppy-remove',
        //'iconOptions' => ['class' => 'text-success'],
        'showHeader' => true,
        'showPageSummary' => true,
        'showFooter' => true,
        'showCaption' => true,
        'fullExportType'=> 'xlsx',
        'filename' => 'Vacancy_Report',
        //'alertMsg' => 'The EXCEL export file will be generated for download.',
        'options' => 'test11',
        //'mime' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'config' => [
            'worksheet' => 'ExportWorksheet',
            'cssFile' => ''
        ],
    ],

        ],

]);
```

Using this classes

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\jui\DatePicker;
use app\models\CandidateEducation;
use app\models\CandidatePreviousEmployment;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\Department;
use app\models\Track;
use app\models\Vacancy;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use Helpers;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use yii\data\Pagination;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
```

My nav code is

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
    <li role="presentation" class=" <?php if(strpos($q,'/index.php?r=site%2Findex')!== false ){echo 'active'; } ?> "><?= Html::a('Home', ['/site/index'], ['class'=> 'col']) ?></li>
    <li role="presentation" <?php if(strpos($q,'/index.php?r=vacancy/index')!== false ){echo "class='active'"; } ?>> <?= Html::a('Vacancy', ['/vacancy'], ['class'=> 'col']) ?></li>
    <li role="presentation" <?php if(strpos($q,'/index.php?r=candidate%2Findex')!== false ){echo "class='active'"; } ?>> <?= Html::a('Candidates', ['/candidate/'], ['class'=> 'col']) ?></li>

     <li role="presentation" <?php if(strpos($q,'/index.php?r=interviewer%2Findex')!== false ){echo "class='active'"; } ?>> <?= Html::a('Interviewers', ['/interviewer'], ['class'=> 'col']) ?></li>
     <li role="presentation" <?php if(strpos($q,'/index.php?r=drive%2Findex')!== false ){echo "class='active'"; } ?>> <?= Html::a('Drives', ['/drive'], ['class'=> 'col']) ?></li>
     <li role="presentation" <?php if(strpos($q,'/index.php?r=question-bank')!== false && strpos($q,'/index.php?r=question-bank%2Fset-question-paper')== false  ){echo "class='active'"; } ?>> <?= Html::a('Question Bank', ['/question-bank'], ['class'=> 'col']) ?></li>
     <li class="dropdown">
     <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="defaultNavbar3" href="#"><b>Question Paper</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li role="presentation" <?php if(strpos($q,'/index.php?r=question-bank%2Fset-question-paper')!== false ){echo "class='active'"; } ?>> <?= Html::a('Set Question Paper', ['/question-bank/set-question-paper'], ['class'=> 'col']) ?></li>
         <li role="presentation" <?php if(strpos($q,'/index.php?r=question-bank%2Fsearch-question-paper')!== false ){echo "class='active'"; } ?>> <?= Html::a('Search Question Paper', ['/question-bank/search-question-paper'], ['class'=> 'col']) ?></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
             <li role="presentation" <?php if(strpos($q,'/index.php?r=offer%2Findex')!== false ){echo "class='active'"; } ?>> <?= Html::a('Offer', ['/offer'], ['class'=> 'col']) ?></li>
     <li class="dropdown">
     <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="defaultNavbar4" href="#"><b>User Role</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li role="presentation" <?php if(strpos($q,'/index.php?r=assignrole%2Findex')!== false ){echo "class='active'"; } ?>> <?= Html::a('Assign Role To User', ['/auth-assignment/index'], ['class'=> 'col']) ?></li>
          <li role="presentation" <?php if(strpos($q,'/index.php?r=role%2Findex')!== false ){echo "class='active'"; } ?>> <?= Html::a('Create Role & Permission', ['/auth-item/index'], ['class'=> 'col']) ?></li>
           <li role="presentation" <?php if(strpos($q,'/index.php?r=assignpermission%2Findex')!== false ){echo "class='active'"; } ?>> <?= Html::a('Assign Permission To Role', ['/auth-item-child/index'], ['class'=> 'col']) ?></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
```

Please help!

Comment: Can try a work around, simply reload the page after print. Lemme know whether it works or not?

Comment: Another work around is to create a new page only for the Nav bar & import in the current page.

Comment: Is it possible that you have multiple bootstrap css file included.One through GridView Asset and one in you AppAsset ??